# How to configure Outlook account via C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, configure, account

Need to configure email, name, mail server and other by c#. How do I do this without using Outlook Redemption?

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d2tx7z6d(v=vs.100) but don't know if outlook.interop supports configuring accounts.

Comment: No, in outlook.interop all properties in read-only mode.

Comment: Just generate the registry file, then run it, simple as pie.

Comment: Try to refer below link. See if this can help
[Using Account Management API (IOlkAccountManger) to List Outlook Email Accounts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27494/Using-Account-Management-API-IOlkAccountManger-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [create a PRF file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062.aspx#BKMK_ManuallyEditing) - either manually or dynamically via your .NET application.

Then, to import the account you launch Outlook with the command line option:

```
outlook.exe /importprf C:\SomePath\FileName.prf
```

This can be done within your C# code using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

Comment: I create .prf file, write key to registry(ImportPRF). But when I start outlook this key is erased. Why? How to import .prf into outlook programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean write key to registry? The invocation of `outlook.exe /importprf ...` should do the import. Registry editing should not be necessary