# How to create an account in outlook programmatically

Tags: windows, outlook, mapi

I wanted to create an account in standalone application like in Outlook.
Have gone through `MAPI interfaces` Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815463.aspx)!  but can't find anything useful.
Also looked for the `Account Manager Api` Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg394258.aspx)!

But here you can only view already added accounts. If you want to create account using `Account Manager Api` , it will prompt a dialog box for adding an account. Which is of no use for me because I want a code for the same.

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Outlook account via C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880930/how-to-configure-outlook-account-via-c)

Answer (score 1):

The parts of the `IOlkAccount` interface related to creating new accounts are not documented. You can use MAPI to add Exchange and PST accounts.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it allows to add POP3/SMTP accounts using [RDOAccounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm).`AddPOP3Account`.

Comment: Please let me know the MAPI interface to add Exchange and PST accounts.

Comment: Use IMsgServiceAdmin::CreateMsgService to add "MSEMS", "MSPST MS" or "MSUPST MS" services to a profile.

Comment: In my c++ code, I want to add a functionality which add MAPI, POP3/SMTP accounts. So, I want to know the interface for that.

Comment: There is no interface for that. At least nothing is documented,. Redemption works directly with the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And Also want to know that Can I use redemption Library in my C/C++ code to add features like Account Creation/Deletion, modify configurations etc. For example, I want to add POP3/SMTP accounts in email client through C/C++ program so can I use redemption library in C/C++ code . What all features are there in redemption (i.e. distributable version license).

Comment: Using Redemption in C++ is not any different from using any other COM library (such as the Outlook Object Model) - use #import statement to import the type library and create the headers, declare and initialize the RDOSession object, etc.

Comment: Through "AddPOP3Account" method, we can add pop3 account. But if we want to add other type of accounts like Exchange, IMAP so for that what interface, method we can use. Apart from POP3 account, what all types of accounts we can add using redemption library.

Comment: Redemption lets you add delegate Exchange mailbox accounts, PST stores, and POP3/SMTP accounts.

Comment: In my C/C++ code, I want to pass outlook object in GetMessageFromID and GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject. So, How can I get the outlook object?

Comment: Can you give me a better context? You might want to post a new question instead..