# How to change Outlook settings programatically with .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I'm working on a script that generates a user in my network. Besides the AD, File-Share and Exchange part of it I want to set some default Outlook settings for the new user. As a start I want to change some calendar settings like holidays and calendar viewing permissions.

[image]

First of all I thought of the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook(v=office.14).aspx) Namespace. Sadly all parameters are read-only. So this didn't work out.

Then I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880930/how-to-configure-outlook-account-via-c) SO post and was confident as hell. Sadly as far as I tried and understand (Source: [Understanding an Outlook profile file](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/understanding-microsoft-outlook-profile-file-prf/)) you can't set those settings in a .prf-file.

And here I ran out of options..  There used to  be a `ADODB` method to interact with Outlook. But as far as I know this doesn't work anymore since Exchange/Outlook 2010.

Thanks in advance for any shared thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the answer is, but I can tell you how to find it.  If you change those settings, close Outlook, and then configure Outlook on a different machine to connect to the same Exchange mailbox, do the settings persist?  Probably not, in which case they're not stored in the mailbox.

If they're not stored in the mailbox, they're probably stored in the registry.  Use procmon or a similar tool to monitor which keys Outlook modified when you change those settings.  You should then be able to just set those keys in your program, but be aware that the exact key may vary with version of Outlook, so you'd want to ask your customer how many versions of Outlook they use in their environment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll give it a try and report the outcomes. I was wondering where those settings are saved anyway as neither on the client, nor on the exchange server were any .prf-files. So Outlook has to pull these default settings from somewhere else.